# Como comparar arrays e datagridview através de laços?

Tags: c#, array, datagridview

Boa tarde pessoal

Eu tenho 7 caixas de texto que eu fiz desse jeito

```
long[] Jornada;
Jornada = new long[7];

           Jornada[0] = TimeSpan.Parse(textboxjornadaseg.Text.ToString()).Ticks;
           Jornada[1]= TimeSpan.Parse(textboxjornadater.Text.ToString()).Ticks;
           Jornada[2] = TimeSpan.Parse(textboxjornadaqua.Text.ToString()).Ticks;
           Jornada[3] = TimeSpan.Parse(textboxjornadaqui.Text.ToString()).Ticks;
           Jornada[4] = TimeSpan.Parse(textboxjornadasex.Text.ToString()).Ticks;
           Jornada[5] = TimeSpan.Parse(textboxjornadasab.Text.ToString()).Ticks;
           Jornada[6] = TimeSpan.Parse(textboxjornadadom.Text.ToString()).Ticks;
```

cada jornada é um maskedtexbox referente a jornada contratual total do dia, tenho um  botão de calcular em que  ele preenche uma linha e joga esse conteúdo em uma célula da grid.

O que eu fiz : coloquei um FOR pra ele pegar as 7 condições e colocar em uma variável : Jornada[i]

```
 for (long i = 0; i < 1; i++)

           {

            IdentificaHoraExtra = HorasDoDia + HorasDaNoite > Jornada[i]; //verifica se há horas extras
            ResultadoHE = IdentificaHoraExtra ? (HorasDoDia + HorasDaNoite) - Jornada[i] : (new TimeSpan(0).Ticks)
            }
```

Ao clicar  ele gera uma linha na datagridview, esse Jornada[i] é um campo de jornada contratual.

O que eu quero fazer: na grid ele tem uma coluna chamada "dia", ai ele pega o dia da semana : "segunda"/ "terça" / [...]  e por ai vai, cada inserção na linha ele acrescenta o próximo dia, eu queria descobrir uma forma em que ele comparasse  a célula do dia com o vetor correspondente e retornasse a identificação do vetor igual a posição do dia na linha.

por exemplo: no datagridview apareceu uma célula escrito "segunda"/ segunda ele pega Jornada[0], na terça ele pega a Jornada[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH87Q.png)

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como eu comparo o índice da em célula que aparece o  dia com o índice que eu criei no array?

Edit colocarei prints para facilitar a visualização

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na primeira imagem acima no campo de jornada de trabalho ele retorna os valores dos textbox.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa segunda imagem nos textbox do lado esquerdo estão os valores que são inseridos no dategridview

No campo de jornada  era pra mostrar o valor da sexta que é 08:00
so que ele pega a segunda todas a vezes
Queria  quero dar um jeito dele identificar o conteúdo do dia para cada valor nesses textbox.

Comment: Por que voce nao armazena o indice do seu array em uma coluna, ou entao simplesmente faz o inverso, sendo que voce sabe que segunda é 0 e assim por diante. Voce tem as duas possibilidades

Comment: WindowsForms, WPF ou WebForms?

Comment: Windows forms!!

Comment: Pessoal eu editei e coloquei as imagens para facilitar a visualização.